# Securing authenticated API calls with NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

First of all , apologies for being an Nginx newb.  We utilize third-party API's that require authentication and we want to secure the API key by setting up a reverse proxy in Nginx.  I'm pretty sure I get how to set up this part - create a `location`, `proxy_pass` it to the third-party server and add in authentication headers.

However, even though the API key is secure, at this point any user has full access to the API through the front-end URL, is that right?  How I would I limit access to the proxied API to requests coming from the web server itself?  Is adding a CORS header the correct solution here?

Part of my confusion is I'm not sure what is the 'origin' of a AJAX request in front-end code?  Does it count as coming from the web server or from the user's computer, since code is executed in their browser?